# Migrate Spring cloud stream listener (kafka) from declarative to functional model

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to migrate an implementation of spring cloud streams (kafka) declarative way to the recommended functional model

In [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive) they say :

> ...a functional programming model in Spring Cloud Stream (SCSt). It’s
> less code, less configuration. Most importantly, though, your code is
> completely decoupled and independent from the internals of SCSt

**My current implementation:**

**Declaring the MessageChanel**

```
@Input(PRODUCT_INPUT_TOPIC)
MessageChannel productInputChannel();
```

**Using `@StreamListener` which is deprecated now**

```
@StreamListener(StreamConfig.PRODUCT_INPUT_TOPIC)
public void addProduct(@Payload Product product, @Header Long header1, @Header String header2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Product> addProduct() {
    return product -> {
        // your code
    };
}
```

I am not sure what is the value of `PRODUCT_INPUT_TOPIC`, but let's assume `input`.

So the s-c-stream will automatically create a binding for you with name `addProduct-in-0`. [Here are the details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.12.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_and_binding_names). You can use it as is, but if you still want to use the custom name, you can use `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.addProduct-in-0=input`. - see more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.12.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names).

If you need access to headers, you can just pass a Message as input argument

Here it is

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<Product>> addProduct() {
    return message -> {
        Product product = message.getPayload();
        // your code
    };
}
```